# Migrations: Omit `remove_column` Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

There's a migration removing a column not needed anymore from a db table. The migration uses the same column parameters which were used on creation.

```
class RemoveSalaryCodeFromProject < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        remove_column :projects, :salary_code, :string, limit: 1, default: 'A', null: false
    end
end
```

Would the following be an alternative writing for the migration above? Meaning it should do exactly the same like `remove_column` with all it's parameters.

```
class RemoveSalaryCodeFromProject < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        remove_column :projects, :salary_code
    end
end
```

If it is a valid alternative, would it be desirable to just write that simple migrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ever need to rollback (i.e. undo) a migration using `rake db:rollback`, it will only work if you supply all of those parameters, otherwise you will get something like:

```
ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration:

remove_column is only reversible if given a type.
```

If you don't ever need to undo migrations, then you can omit the extra parameters.

Comment: That source helped to understand the reversible removals, too: http://www.reinteractive.net/posts/178-reversible-migrations-with-active-record

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: You can simplify it if you don't care about rollbacks.

In general you can just use

`remove_column :table, :column_name`

and it will just remove the column.

HOWEVER, if you want to have that in a fully functional `change` method you will need to provide the extra parameters.

```
def change
  remove_column :projects, :salary_code, :string, limit: 1, default: 'A', null: false
end
```

so that it would be used be `add_column` in a rollback.

check the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/remove_column)